# Is the quantum zeno effect observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Does the quantum zeno and anti zeno effect get observed. Under the Copenhagen interpretation, the quantum zeno effect should not only be observed, but the measurement frame rate should be enough to predict the exact probability of arrival times. Is this true?

Comment: What arrival time do you mean?

Comment: Free Particle moving towards a screen

Comment: Are you specifically requesting references for it being observed in position variables? Quantum Zeno measurements are experimentally established but I think mostly in atomic systems. See eg [Wayne M. Itano, D. J. Heinzen, J. J. Bollinger, and D. J. Wineland
Phys. Rev. A 41, 2295](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.2295).

Answer (score 3):

An overview of experiments on the quantum zeno effect can be found on its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect#Experiments_and_discussion). The first observation of the effect seems to be presented in [Wayne M. Itano, D. J. Heinzen, J. J. Bollinger, and D. J. Wineland "Quantum Zeno effect"
*Phys. Rev. A* **41**, 2295 (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.2295).